# Why I keep getting wrong answer in this math problem?

Tags: javascript

I need help with this logic math problem in Uri Online Judge site:
[image]
**The submitted code starts in "var limit"**, I used the var lines to work with an example of input:

```
var lines = ["4", "14", "123", "10", "-25"];  
/**
 * Code your solution here
 */
var limit = 0;
var inside = 0;
var out =  0;

for (i=0; i<=limit; i++) {
  var number = parseInt(lines.shift());
  if (number>-10000 && number<10000) {    
    i = number;
    limit++;
} else {
    i--;
  }
}

for (a=0; a<=i--; a++) {
  if (a >=10 && a<=20) {
      inside++;
} else {
    out++;
  }
}

console.log(inside + " in");
console.log(out + " out");
```

so, when I submit this:
[image]
it shows as being "Wrong Answer" and I don't know what I did wrong.

Comment: Since `limit = 0` (since that is what you assigned it to be), `for (i=0; i<=limit; i++)` seems a bit pointless. It is also odd that the loop `for (a=0; a<=i--; a++)` doesn't actually involve the numbers in the list. You seem to be checking if the *indices* are between 10 and 20, not the numbers themselves.

Comment: Your loops are wrong. If you want to look at the `number` you parsed later on, you will need to store them in an array. `for (a = 0; a <= i--; a++)` is definitely not what you want. When you set `i = number;` it just overwrites `i` on the next iteration of the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
var lines = input.split('\n');
```

where you get as first element the length of the following values.

Your loop looks then like

```
var limit = parseInt(lines[0], 10); // take a radix as well

for (var i = 1; i <= limit; i++) { // start from one
    var number = parseInt(lines[i], 10); // take value directly without mutating the array
```

Then you need no check if the value is in the wanted range bcause the page just gives you more information. You could check if the integer value of Javascript fits into this range by looking to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators.

But you can check if the value is inside of the interval [10, 20]

```
    if (number >= 10 && number <= 20) {
        inside++;
    }
}
// finally
out = limit - inside;
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about the logic in your code. You can achieve a solution with 1 loop. I coded a sample solution in C below. You should take a look, understand the logic and then, convert it to javascript.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int N, in_range = 0, out_range = 0, cur_num;
  scanf("%d", &N);

  for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    scanf("%d", &cur_num);

    if (cur_num >= 10 && cur_num <= 20) in_range++;
    else out_range++;
  }

  printf("%d in\n", in_range);
  printf("%d out\n", out_range);

  return 0;
}
```